# Can I test a compiled and linked C++ program with TestNG and Java test cases?

Tags: java, testing, java-native-interface, automated-tests, testng

I am familiar with C++ programming and now Im learning Java to write TestNG based tests. To clearify my question: if I write a little software in C++ then compile and link it to get an executable, can I write test cases in Java/TestNG that can access to the C++ based software and test its funtionalities? If yes, how the interfacing between Java test cases and the binary code exactly works?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect Java and C++ through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jni. (But it's gonna be a long, steep road.)

You can set up Java classes/objects that talk to the C++-code via JNI, and then of course you can write TestNG-unit tests for those Java classes.

Note that your C code does not need to be linked into a binary, you will just need the compiled object code.

Comment: I guess what I'm really saying there is that you seem to have a hammer ("I want to learn TestNG"), and you're confusing a screw ("C++ unit tests") with a nail ("Java unit test").